# Spark - Find average by Key

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```py
def AvgCount(cnt,tot):
    count = cnt
    total = tot
    return(count,total)

realEstate = SpContext.textFile("c:/temp/RealEstate.txt")
realEstate.collect()

rdd = realEstate.filter(lambda x: "Bedroom" not in x)
rdd1 = rdd.map(lambda line: (line.split(",")[3],(AvgCount(1,(line.split(",")[2])))))

rdd1.collect()

housePriceTotal = rdd1.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:AvgCount(x.count + y.count,x.total + y.total))

for bedroom, avgCount in housePriceTotal.collect():

    print ("{}: ({},{})". format(bedroom,avgCount.count,avgCount.total))
```

I get type error as below and not sure the reason for it. I need to find the Average price according to the bedrooms.

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +:
>   'builtin_function_or_method' and 'builtin_function_or_method'

Sample file -

```
House,No,Bedroom,Price
0,1,10000,5
0,1,20000,8
0,1,5000,2
0,1,10100,5
0,1,21000,8
0,1,5100,2
```

Comment: You should convert it into a dataframe and use a `df.groupby("key").avg()`

Comment: I want to use RDD rather than dataframe for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

`x.count` is a method. If you want the value, use `x.count()`.
The error means you are trying to sum 2 functions which is absurd.

Comment: count is variable for method AvgCount and im not using inbuilt method count().

Comment: Thanks Guys. I was able to resolve it -  
                                                                                                               rdd1.collect()
housePriceTotal = rdd1.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:AvgCount(int(x[0]) + int(y[0]),int(x[1]) + int(y[1])))

housePriceTotal = rdd1.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:AvgCount(int(x[0])+ int(y[0]),int(x[1]) + int(y[1])))

for i,j in housePriceTotal.collect():
    print (i,j[0],j[1],j[1]/j[0])